# I have an error " Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0yoC.jpg)

I opened the project and i got this error, i don't think i can do this with code, i would appreciate it if someone can help.I don't know what to do about it and I've tried many ways, I am getting errors from classes that I have not encountered before and I have never received such an error (please take a look at the photo above).

Comment: Please add the actual root error message to make it possible for someone to help you and others to benefit from any answer.  “Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code” is just a generic message.  You need to expand the rows in the image you sent to see the real cause. Also please embed images rather than linking them in the future.

Comment: Try cleaning your Build(Product-> Clean Build Folder or ⇧⌘K) and cleaning your Build Folder(Option + Product-> Clean Build Folder or Option+⇧⌘K)

Comment: This is not working :(

Answer (score 2):

1. Do you use Eureka pod?
   I had the same `Segmentation Fault: 11` issue with Eureka on xcode 12 (please see [related github](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka/issues/2057) issue). Solution: update Eureka to 5.3.0 (or higher)
2. Do you use another pod that is not updated to use xcode 12?
3. Another possible way to fix that: clean build folder (Product > Clean Build Folder) + clean Derived Data Folder (`rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`). And then just build project again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error but I am not certain what the causes was.

However,the steps below helped me fix the error:

*Product > Clean Build Folder (command + shift + k)*

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29885564)

Answer (score 0):

This error actually occurs when the same name is used in 2 files, and the solution is to change the name of the last file you created.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue in Xcode Version 13.4.1.
Able to resolve by unchecking Open using Rosetta.

[image]